# Crashed: WebThread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000001a00ac1bc in iOS 14.4

Tags: ios

> I am getting a lot of reports on Crashlytics of this WebThread crash in cellForItemAtIndexPath for below line

CarousalCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CarousalCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

> all crashes for only ios 14.4, any suggestions?

Sample Code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    
    CarousalCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CarousalCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (IS_IPAD)
    cell.imgCarousal.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
    else
    cell.imgCarousal.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    if (_arrCarousal.count > 0) {
        NSDictionary *dict = [_arrCarousal objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        Home_Content *content = (Home_Content*)dict;
        [cell.imgCarousal sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",content.image]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Artboard"]];
    }
    else
       {
           [cell.imgCarousal setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Artboard"]];
       
       }

    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
    return cell;
}

Crashed: WebThread
    0  libdispatch.dylib              0x1879da450 _dispatch_assert_queue_fail + 112
    1  libdispatch.dylib              0x1879da3d8 dispatch_assert_queue$V2$VARIANT$mp + 144
    2  UIKitCore                      0x18ab29f24 -[UIImageView _mainQ_beginLoadingIfApplicable] + 72
    3  UIKitCore                      0x18ab22328 -[UIImageView setHidden:] + 72
    4  UIKitCore                      0x18ab42b84 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 1236
    5  UIKitCore                      0x18ab20c48 -[UIImageView initWithCoder:] + 92
    6  UIFoundation                   0x1909d6edc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 696
    7  UIFoundation                   0x1909d70f4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1232
    8  UIFoundation                   0x190963854 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 308
    9  UIKitCore                      0x18ab42a90 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 992
    10 UIFoundation                   0x1909d6edc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 696
    11 UIFoundation                   0x1909d70f4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1232
    12 UIFoundation                   0x190963854 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 308
    13 UIKitCore                      0x18ab42a90 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 992
    14 UIKitCore                      0x189e1a68c -[UICollectionReusableView initWithCoder:] + 68
    15 UIKitCore                      0x189e1c410 -[UICollectionViewCell initWithCoder:] + 68
    16 UIKitCore                      0x18a2a935c -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2196
    17 UIFoundation                   0x1909d6edc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 696
    18 UIFoundation                   0x190963854 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 308
    19 UIKitCore                      0x18a2ad544 -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 128
    20 UIFoundation                   0x1909d6edc UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 696
    21 UIFoundation                   0x1909d70f4 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1232
    22 UIFoundation                   0x190963854 -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 308
    23 UIKitCore                      0x18a2a84fc -[NSCoder(UIIBDependencyInjectionInternal) _decodeObjectsWithSourceSegueTemplate:creator:sender:forKey:] + 488
    24 UIKitCore                      0x18a2aaed4 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1064
    25 UIKitCore                      0x189dfb3e4 -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:viewCategory:] + 912
    26 UIKitCore                      0x189dfba44 -[UICollectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:] + 100
    27 [MyAppName]                       0x104ba8448 -[CarousalCollectionViewCell collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:] + 292 (CarousalCollectionViewCell.m:292)
    28 UIKitCore                      0x189de8984 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 408
    29 UIKitCore                      0x189ded514 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 5520
    30 UIKitCore                      0x189df1ac0 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 320
    31 UIKitCore                      0x18ab72398 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2468
    32 QuartzCore                     0x18b077df4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 288
    33 QuartzCore                     0x18b07e398 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 520
    34 QuartzCore                     0x18b0896e8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 140
    35 QuartzCore                     0x18afd4d7c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 416
    36 QuartzCore                     0x18affef40 CA::Transaction::commit() + 728
    37 QuartzCore                     0x18b0001f0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
    38 CoreFoundation                 0x187d7c87c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
    39 CoreFoundation                 0x187d76f50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 604
    40 CoreFoundation                 0x187d76bf4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 656
    41 WebCore                        0x194fe3b1c <redacted> + 672
    42 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d05dfc9c _pthread_start + 288
    43 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1d05e4880 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: Does your cell implements a WebView?

Comment: Provide more details and/or sample code of what you are doing in cellForItemAt().

Comment: @Nandish please check updated information with sample code.

Comment: @Larme Not implements WebView.

Comment: can you also provide where you have set  : "CarousalCell" as identifier?

Comment: @Nandish i'm added Cell on ViewController which is having CollectionView & set "CarousalCell" as identifier for Cell.

Comment: Did you call UI operation in async-thread?